# Manager classes benefits

Tags: java

I am wondering if there are any other advantages to using new classes for managers, eg game state managers, other than readability/organization.

Comment: I can see some: Code reuse, maintainability, work division between different programmers. If you're trying to convince yourself to do it, well it's very suggested to do it :)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

If you mean performance (Speed, Memory,...), then No.

However, It is still worth it. Imagine you stop working for 6 months on your application/program and then come back to improve it, would you prefer named and ordered classes or one Main with 15k lines of code?

[KISS](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/20262/keep-it-simple-stupid-principle-kiss-principle)

Comment: Yeah that definitely makes sense, thanks for the swift reply